# Use ChoiseType's invalid message in Symfony 5

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony5, invalidation

I create a form type in Symfony 5 and use this in `$builder` :

```
    ->add(
        $builder
            ->create('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                    'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
                    'Ban' => 'ROLE_BAN'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Choose Role!'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($roles) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return $roles[0] ?? null;
                },
                function ($roles) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return [$roles];
                }
            ))
    )
```

But `NotBlank` not work!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You may be after `invalid_message` attribute. 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#invalid-message

Comment: @JovanPerovic When I use `invalid_message` when submit form, error not show because my ChoiceType return empty data not null